# Is there a way for a TextInput to behave like a button i.e. be able to be selected (onPress)?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, tags

I am making a react native health app in which the user can select tags to describe certain symptoms they are facing. I am trying to let the user create their own tags, at the moment the user can enter tags but cannot select them. Is there a way to allow them to select text inputs?

I have already tried wrapping touchable opacity around it but when I press the text input the cursor just focuses on the word (wanting me to edit the word).

I have also tried editable = {false} this removes the ability for the user to enter a text input completely. Is there a way to allow the user to input a value once and then disable the text input (non-editable)?

Or If I used Button instead of TextInput is there a way for the user to enter the title of the button so it can act as a tag?

Here is how I have allowed users to create text inputs

```js
 addTextInput = (index) => {
    let textInput = this.state.textInput;
    textInput.push(
        <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.addValues(text, index)}
            editable={true}              
        />
    );

    this.setState({ textInput });
}

removeTextInput = () => {
    let textInput = this.state.textInput;
    let inputData = this.state.inputData;
    textInput.pop();
    inputData.pop();
    this.setState({ textInput, inputData });
}
```

and this is what my current tags look like:

[image]

on the picture when the user presses the plus a new tag/TextInput is created, what I want is when the user presses it, it should be able to change color or the like.

here is the code for the plus button:

```js
<View style={{
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    flexGrow: '1', 
    flexWrap: 'wrap', 
    width: Responsive.width(300)
}}>
    
    {this.state.textInput.map((value) => {
        return value
    })}

    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
        this.addTextInput(this.state.textInput.length)
    }}>
        <Image
            style={{ marginLeft: 8, width: 38, height: 38 }}
            source={require('../../../assets/plusButton.png')}
        />
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

    {/* <Button title='Get Values' onPress={() => this.getValues()} /> */}

</View>

<View style={styles.row}>
    <View style={{ margin: 10, top: Responsive.height(75) }}>
        <Button onPress={() => this.removeTextInput()}>Remove</Button>
    </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved it with a TouchableOpacity over a TextInput. Using  zIndex and absolute positioning you can expand the TouchableOpacity over your text input and transform it in a button, the TouchableOpacity must have a 100% opacity.
You can control with { condition &&  } your logic to make it behave like a button or a TextInput.

```
export default function App() {
  const [m,setm]=React.useState(false);
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{zIndex:10, position:'absolute', width: '100%', height: '100%', opacity:'100%'}} onPress={()=>{setm(!m)}} />
      <TextInput style={{zIndex:1,backgroundColor:'#fbb',color:'#000'}} value={m}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```